# strange behavior in passing formula to npcdensbw() function in np package

Tags: r, formula

I am attempting to include a call to `np::npcdensbw()` inside another function that I am writing. As such, I want to be able to pass the formula for the conditional density to `npcdensbw()` as a variable. However, when I do so I get an error, and I cannot figure out why. Minimal example:

```r
####### Testing data
N <- 100 # sample size

x_cont <- rnorm(N)
x_dis <- rbinom(N, 1, .5)

# errors
e <- rnorm(N)

# depvar
y <- as.numeric((x_cont + .5 * x_dis + e) > 0)

df <- data.frame(y, x_cont, x_dis)
```

When I write the formula out and call the function directly it executes no problem:

```r
# Estimate conditional density of y
ycdens <- np::npcdensbw(as.factor(y) ~ x_cont + as.factor(x_dis), df)
```

But since I would like to call this function from another, I need to pass along the formula as an argument, and when I do so it does not work:

```r
# create  formula object
f <- formula(as.factor(y) ~ x_cont + as.factor(x_dis))

ycdens2 <- np::npcdensbw(f, df) # doesnt work
#> Error in names(res) <- c("response", "terms"): 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

ycdens2 <- np::npcdensbw(deparse(f), df) # doesnt work
#> Error in npcdensbw.conbandwidth(xdat = xdat, ydat = ydat, bws = tbw): number of rows of 'ydat' does not match 'xdat'\

func <- function(form, data) {
           np::npcdensbw(form, data)
  }
func(as.factor(y) ~ x_cont + as.factor(x_dis), df) # doesnt work
# Error in names(res) <- c("response", "terms") : 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this is occurring or how I can circumvent it. The error I get when used within a function appears to come from the function `explodeFormula()` the code for which I found on the `np` [github page](https://github.com/JeffreyRacine/R-Package-np/tree/master/R) and is simply:

```r
explodeFormula <- function(formula){
  res <- strsplit(strsplit(paste(deparse(formula), collapse=""),
                           " *[~] *")[[1]], " *[+] *")
  stopifnot(all(sapply(res,length) > 0))
  names(res) <- c("response","terms")
  res
}
```

This code does not throw an error when I call it on an arbitrary formula so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is unfortunately not coded in a way that you could easily pass a variable.

Looking at `npcdensbw.formula()`, it does a `match.call` before the call to `explodeFormula()` where it crashes (as you already point out correctly).

This means that `deparse(formula)` will simply be the variable (string) you have passed in the call, e.g. `"f"` or `"form"` in your examples above.

If the code of `explodeFormula()` would call `deparse(eval(formula))` instead, this might work.

Simple example:

```
explodeFormula <- function(formula) {
  res <- strsplit(strsplit(paste(deparse(formula), collapse=""),
                           " *[~] *")[[1]], " *[+] *")
  stopifnot(all(sapply(res,length) > 0))
  names(res) <- c("response","terms")
  res
}

myFunc <- function(x, ...) {
  mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  explodeFormula(mf[["x"]])
}

ff <- as.factor(y) ~ x_cont + as.factor(x_dis)

myFunc(ff)
myFunc(as.factor(y) ~ x_cont + as.factor(x_dis))

explodeFormula <- function(formula) {
     res <- strsplit(strsplit(paste(deparse(eval(formula)), collapse=""), " *[~] *")[[1]], " *[+] *")
     stopifnot(all(sapply(res,length) > 0))
     names(res) <- c("response","terms")
     res
}

myFunc(ff)
$response
[1] "as.factor(y)"

$terms
[1] "x_cont"           "as.factor(x_dis)"
```

Comment: thanks for your detective work. so is it fair to conclude that I cannot use this conditional density estimator within a function? any thoughts on a workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes, looks difficult to do something from the outside. possible work-around without waiting for an update by the package maintainer would be to fork on Github, modify yourself and re-build. Or alternatively substitute the function `explodeFormula` or `npcdensbw` in `np`s package namespace with modified version

Comment: good ideas. i figured out a temporary workaround using `assignInNamespace` and swapping your improved version of `explodeFormula` for the original